# How can I create a page with multiple languages?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have just created .properties with its values and JSP file

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language :
        not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="ge.web.content.i18n.text" />
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP/JSTL i18n demo</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <a href="">ENGLISH </a> <br>
        <a href="">PARIS</a>
            <form method="post">
                <label for="username"><fmt:message key="login.label.username" />:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
                <br>
                <label for="password"><fmt:message key="login.label.password" />:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <br>
            <fmt:message key="login.button.submit" var="buttonValue" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="${buttonValue}">
        </form> <br> text from database here.
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Question 1)** It takes the username and password from my properties file (default English). It works, but the text is not shown in the button. Key "login.label.password" is correct.

**Question 2)** When I click on a link, for example `PARIS`,  I need to change text from the properties file. How can I do that? How can i change locale? I think I should write in session, because I need to change the language from the database too.

**Question 3)** With changing the properties file's text, I need the language text from the database too (without changing the link). How can I achieve this?

**Questin 4** Should I use JSTL, or should I save the language in the session and redirect with something like this `?language="EN"`?

Comment: Is it a legacy project? If you can I suggest you going with JSF instead of scriptlets. You're using a technology that's more than 10 years old instead of it. With JSF what you want to achieve is straight forward.

Comment: Huh? The code example doesn't use scriptlets.

Comment: No its not big project. So I don't need JSF :-)

Comment: In the future, ask one question per Question. That's easier answering and finding duplicates. The current duplicate answers your first question.